# uno.toolkit.ui: how to use Card or Divider control on Skia.Gtk platorm

Tags: uno-platform

I try to use Divider and Card control from the uno.toolkit.ui package:

```xml
<utu:Divider SubHeader="Uno.Material Controls:" 
            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDividerStyle}" />

<utu:Card HeaderContent="Header Outlined card With supporting text"
            SubHeaderContent="With supporting text"
            SupportingContent="This is the supporting text"
            Style="{StaticResource MaterialOutlinedCardStyle}" />
```

when I run the sample, I get a lot of messages like:

```
warn: Uno.UI.ResourceResolver[0]
      Couldn't statically resolve resource MaterialOutlinedCardContentControlStyle

warn: Uno.UI.ResourceResolver[0]
      Couldn't statically resolve resource MaterialDividerStyle

warn: Uno.UI.ResourceResolver[0]
```

and the Controls are not displayed. Using the TabBar - Control from the Toolkit works.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to follow instructions as described in the `README` page on the [uno.toolkit.ui](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno.toolkit.ui) repo...

Since the reference to the missing style (`MaterialDividerStyle` for the `<Divider>` control) is defined in the [`MaterialToolkitResources` dictionary](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno.toolkit.ui/blob/20fbb909bb28cce6a41666905fdc20b97fae3dd0/src/library/Uno.Toolkit.Material/MaterialToolkitResources.cs#L43), you need to add a reference to it in your `App.xaml` file, like that:

```xml
<!-- App.xaml: -->

    <!--  Load Uno.UI.Toolkit resources  -->
    <ToolkitResources xmlns="using:Uno.Toolkit.UI" />

    <!--  Load Material resources  -->
    <MaterialColors xmlns="using:Uno.Material" />
    <MaterialResources xmlns="using:Uno.Material" />

    <!--  Load Material Toolkit resources  -->
    <MaterialToolkitResources xmlns="using:Uno.Toolkit.UI.Material" />
```

Comment: I had setup the MaterialToolkitResources in my App.xaml exactly the way described in the README page. That isn't the problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem. The package Uno.Toolkit.UI.Material must be installed. After doing that it worked. Unfortunately that isn't mentioned in any README. After reading the README I thought it is enough to install only Uno.Toolkit.UI package

Comment: @UweSteinkohl Can you point to the documentation that you were using, maybe we can update it. The README on the Toolkit repo has changed since April and we now have documentation for the Toolkit here: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/external/uno.toolkit.ui/doc/getting-started.html

Although, I am looking at the old README and it seems it was already addressing the need for Uno.Toolkit.Material: Step 3 at https://github.com/unoplatform/uno.toolkit.ui/blob/1600ed66504dc7d543f8632b8978c90ee8f7db24/README.md